# Reading Registry key in Matlab

Tags: matlab, registry, registrykey

I am trying to read the following registry key in matlab

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Installer\UserData\S-1-5-18\Components\4D8041334C8956A4240A50360E36FD42
```

I am using the function

```
winqueryreg('HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE','SOFTWARE','\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Installer\UserData\S-1-5-18\Components\4D8041334C8956A4240A50360E36FD42')
```

but I get this error

```
Error using winqueryreg
Cannot query value of type REG_NONE.
```

Can anyone tell me where I am going wrong, and how to read this key??

Answer (score 3):

If you run regedit you will see that you are now on 'map level', you need to add a key identifier.

Please try:

```
yourVal = winqueryreg('HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE','SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Installer\UserData\S-1-5-18\Components\4D8041334C8956A4240A50360E36FD42', YOUR_EXPLICIT_REG);
```

Or if you do not know this key identifier a priori:

```
yourKeys = winqueryreg('name', 'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE','SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Installer\UserData\S-1-5-18\Components\4D8041334C8956A4240A50360E36FD42')

yourVal = winqueryreg('HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE','SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Installer\UserData\S-1-5-18\Components\4D8041334C8956A4240A50360E36FD42', yourKeys{1})
```

and so on...

Comment: Well, I think I am facing another problem. I can't read any subkey under 'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE'. Whenever I give a path as subkey argument(like you suggested in your answer), I am getting the error 'Specified key is invalid'. If I give only 'SOFTWARE' as subkey, I get 'Cannot query value of type REG_NONE'. Any insight??

Comment: I think you need to add 'name' as first argument, Matlab will generate then generate a list of keys available on this level.

yourKeys = winqueryreg('name', 'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE', 'SOFTWARE...')

Comment: Well the problem was basically, I was using my 32 bit Matlab to read the registry for a 64 bit program. This is explained [here](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/support/solutions/en/data/1-F3OHX2/index.html?product=ML&solution=1-F3OHX2). Maybe this will interest you.

Comment: The answer is actually not accurate, at least as of MATLAB 2015b. yourKeys = winqueryreg('name', 'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE',...)  returns only a list of **values** under the given key, not subkeys.   This is clearly documented (http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/winqueryreg.html) and I'd be surprised if the semantics changed across versions.